# Feature-Site Theme activation leads to error

Tags: 2007

When I click on the site collection features>Activate(Theme) it is leading to this error.
This is happening when I click on site Actions>Create new site and selecting blog under sites and workspaces.
Please help me with troubleshooting this.I have done some research and saw that some DLLs might be missing or some references are not working properly.

```
Feature '9aafa318-8619-4726-8531-660edf9221ff' could not be installed because the loading of event receiver assembly "DCCTheme, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=43bbb856e4d7825b" failed: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DCCTheme, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=43bbb856e4d7825b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
File name: 'DCCTheme, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=43bbb856e4d7825b' 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject() 

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. 
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. 
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. 
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services.

New Update : This error is only happening with few new servers. This used to work fine before in the old windows server 2003. So the conclusion is it is server specific.Now how do I make it work in the new servers?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the issue, where the dcctheme.dll is missing from the GAC assembly. On one of the server I was able to create the sites, hence I searched for the .dll in the assembly and simply copied it over to the assembly of other servers and BOOM it all started working.